# large 3d numpy array failed to allocate in python image processing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I want to analyse a 3d array by creating np.zeros and fill it in.
However I cannot allocate the array due to memory error. Here is the code:

The previous code basically creates an array and label it. The array has 200 images with 900*900 pixels.

```py
label, num = ndimage.label(array, structure=struct)
```

The error occurs in this line:

```py
new_img = np.zeros((200, 900, 900), dtype='uint8')
```

which gives error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yifan/PycharmProjects/X-ray process/pore_analysis_batch2.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_img = np.zeros((200, 900, 900), dtype='uint8')
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 154. MiB for an array with shape (200, 900, 900) and data type uint8
```

I've changed the memory limits in windows settings and the 154MiB seems to be too small to cause a memory error. I'm new to python and this error get me stuck for a while, please help me guys!